# Conditional div with blazor server

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

Here is what I want to do:

```
@if (condition)
{
  <div class="test">
}
<span class="test2">...</span>
@if (condition)
{
  </div>
}
```

This does not work because the Blazor compiler thinks the div is never closed.

So I need to do this:

```
@if (condition)
{
  <div class="test">
        <span class="test2">...</span>
  </div>
}
else
{
   <span class="test2">...</span>
}
```

It works fine, but I have a big code redundancy with the span.

How can I do this properly?

Please note div and span are examples. In reality, my code is bigger.

Thanks

Comment: Could you just make the `class` conditional instead of the div?  Rendering a div with a blank class shouldn't cause an issue?

Comment: No i can’t. The div is an exemple if have multiple lines of code in fact.

Comment: Saw your comment after answering, I've added a second possibility.  If neither of those work it might be worth extending the example in your question further.

Comment: Maybe you should break it into separate components. I understand it's a simple example, but more detail about why you would want to do it like this in the first place would be good.

Comment: [Polite] You may not like the syntax, but that's the way it works.   If you want tighter code create the class file directly and build the RenderFragment using the RenderFragmentBuilder.  I agree it can be a little verbose..  but ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is really a Razor syntax issue rather than specifically a Blazor issue.  This [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20338335/1879019) cover it well.

So, you can do what you're trying to do in the first example, but there are also other ways of solving that issue, at least one of which is Blazor specific (there are more no doubt):

### Make the `class` conditional

Rather than trying to not render the `div`, you could make the `class` itself conditional.

So in the `code` section of your page you could declare a property:

```
@code {

    string myClass = "";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (condition) 
        {
            myClass = "whatever";
        }
    }

}
```

And then use that in your razor:

```
<div class='@myClass'> 
    <span class="test2">...</span>
</div>
```

That way the span is only on the page once.

### Split the common code into a separate component

Another approach is to make the common part (the span in this case) into a separate component and then render that component conditionally:

```
@if (condition)
{
    <div class="test">
        <YourComponent />
    </div>
}
else
{
    <YourComponent />
}
```

That's probably overkill for the span in your example, but makes more sense where the new component would be replacing multiple lines of code.

Comment: I have think to work with a component but i need to create an additional file for this...

Comment: @Bob5421, sorry, not following you, is there an issue with an extra file?  I've added a link to another question in my answer that gives some wider context on this.